# Send/Include 'name' field to Mailchimp using API with AJAX

Tags: ajax, forms, api, mailchimp

I need to know how to send the 'name' field to Mailchimp so that it shows the 'name' the user submitted under the name column on the 'subscribers' page in Mailchimp.

**The form looks like this:**

```
<div id="email">
<form action="subscribe.php" id="invite" method="POST">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name.." name="name" id="name" class="name" data-validate="validate(name)"/>
            <input type="email" placeholder="and your email address.." name="email" id="MCE-email" class="email" data-validate="validate(required, email)"/>
<p>If you agree with the Terms and Privacy, please press the submit button below.</p>

<div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
</form>
<div id="clear"></div>
<div id="result"></div>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#invite').ketchup().submit(function() {
if ($(this).ketchup('isValid')) {
var action = $(this).attr('action');
$.ajax({
url: action,
type: 'POST',
data: {
email: $('#MCE-email').val()
},
success: function(data){
$('#result').html(data).css('color', '#a1a1a1', 'padding', '10px 0px 0px 0px');
},
error: function() {
$('#result').html('Sorry, an error occurred.').css('color', 'white');
}
});
}
return false;
});
});
v</script>
```

**The subscribe.php script looks like this :**

```
<?php
$apiKey = 'MYAPIKEY';
$listId = 'MYLISTID';
$double_optin=false;
$send_welcome=false;
$email_type = 'html';
$email = $_POST['email'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
//replace us2 with your actual datacenter
$submit_url = "http://us5.api.mailchimp.com/1.3/?method=listSubscribe";
$data = array(
'email_address'=>$email,
'apikey'=>$apiKey,
'id' => $listId,
'double_optin' => $double_optin,
'send_welcome' => $send_welcome,
'email_type' => $email_type
);
$payload = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $submit_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, urlencode($payload));

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
$data = json_decode($result);
if ($data->error){
echo $data->error;
} else {
    echo "Thank you for your email. We'll keep you up to date..";
}

?>
```

**The field tag of the 'name' field on my form in Mailchimp is 'NAME'**

I hope this is all the information you need and it makes sense..

Thank you greatly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Going off of the Mailchimp listSubscribe function documentation found here:
http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/1.3/listsubscribe.func.php

You just need to create a merge_vars array that will hold any additional fields associated with the subscribing email. For example:

```
$merge_vars = array('FNAME'=>'first name', 'LNAME'=>'last name');
```

And then just pass that array in your $data.